# while processing pdf it is showing error as "file is too big for the current operation"

Tags: c#

I am using Datalogics for processing pdfs. I am merging more pdf files to single pdf file which creates a temporary file for doing this process. After saving the pdf to the mentioned path, temp file should be deleted and file should be sent for print. mean while, it is showing error as "file is too big for the current opertaion". I dont know why it is showing such exception.

Comment: firstly narrow down at which bit of your code it is telling you the file is too big, so you can be sure which file it is on about

Comment: Does it exceed 2Gb - I think that is the size limit on PDF files.

Comment: Please share your code and size of pdf file

Comment: file size is just 84 kb. No idea why it has thrown the exception